# How to take a whole page of content that is hidden and only show a specific piece when clicked via anchor

Tags: jquery, hide, show-hide, hidden

I have a bunch of content on a page that has anchors to locate each one, the anchors are basically like the bookmarks and the content that the anchors lead to i used hide(); with the exception of the first paragraph, because it's just introductory stuff.
What my end result goal is:
When I click on an anchor it will unhide just that ONE paragraph and keep the rest hidden.
Then when I click on another anchor it re-hides the previous paragraph and shows just the content in the anchored paragraph I just clicked

What I have so far (which really isn't much) is:

```
                      $('#content p:not("#firstParagph")').toggle();`
```

I tried to use .filter(':hidden') and show() but it ended up breaking all the code (I'm sure it's because I was doing something wrong though)  How I've gotten it to work previously is to replace the css code display:inline but I want to do it without having to change the CSS because all the css is already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.trigger').click(function(e) // Trigger is the common class for all the anchors
{
     $('#content p').hide(); // Hide all the paragraphs initially. This makes all the visible paragraphs to hide
     $('#content p#'+$(this).attr('src')).show(); // Showing the paragraph which ID is matching to the anchor's src attribute
}
```

Check a sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8WYpS/).

Comment: It worked like a charm!!! I am seeing that my main problem is when i try to concatenate 'this' That's where I'm getting into all the trouble.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="intro"> 
  <a href="intro">Intro</a>
  <p>intro</p>
</div>
<div class="first"> 
  <a href="#">1st</a>
  <p>First</p>
</div>
<div class="second">
  <a href="#">2nd</a>
  <p>Second</p>
</div>
<div class="third"> 
  <a href="#">3rd</a>
  <p>third</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('p').hide();
$('.intro p').show();

$('a').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('p').hide();
   $(this).closest('div').find('p').show();
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SznuP/

Comment: Thank you very for this!It's very close to what i needed! I think I can figure it out from this point though, Thank you again!